# Issue with TF2.0 Custom Generator

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to learn how to use the tf.data.Dataset methods and working on a custom generator from a CSV file. The CSV holds three data points. 1 the path to the image, 2 the label, 3 the image name (Not used). What I am trying to do is read in the CSV in pandas and then iterate over each roll yeilding the read in an image (Keras load_image) and the lable which was encoded using Pandas.  It gives me this error which makes me think it is the generator issue as it is not doing what it should.

> ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.

This is my code that I am working with.

```py
    csv_path = '../Dataset/ShowData.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    base_path = "../Dataset/"
    # Make one hot encoding for lables
    le = LabelEncoder()
    df['Label'] = le.fit_transform(df['Label'])
    print(df.head(1)['Label'])
    print(df.tail(1)['Label'])
    '''
    # View the labels (if you want)
    list(encoder.classes_)
    # Convert some integers into their category names
    list(encoder.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
    '''

    def process_dataframe(dataframe):
        for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
            # print(row['Path'], row['Label'])
            # Load image and get lable
            img_path = os.path.join(base_path, row['Path'])
            img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 200))
            img = img_to_array(img)
            img = img/255  # normalize the image
            label = row['Label']
            #label = to_categorical(label, num_classes, dtype=tf.float32)
            yield img, label


    def generate_dataset(dataframe):
        generator = lambda: process_dataframe(dataframe)
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=generator,
                                          output_types= (tf.float32, tf.int32))


    dataset = generate_dataset(df)
    data_batch = dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(32)
    print(data_batch)

    model = Sequential([
        Flatten(input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

    model.fit(data_batch, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Oh this is what the data_batch prints out

```
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (<unknown>, <unknown>), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

And this is the label type

```
Name: Label, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `output_shapes` for the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` call. You can find the documentation at the [Tensorflow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#from_generator).

Comment: I did here return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=generator,
                                          output_types= (tf.float32, tf.int32))

Comment: def generate_dataset(dataframe): in this method. Does that matter if the generator is not defined in the main method but in a function?

Comment: @MNM You defined the `output types` not the `output shapes`